# no sound playing on live site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio, console

I'm having a problem with my live site. When we made the site the sound worked completely but then when we put it up on the domain the sound doesn't seem to work. We've ran error tests and it seems that the sound is running in the console log but not actually running on the site.

sound only appearing in the console log.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5oAd.jpg

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    playSound: function (clip) { //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen
        if ($("#sound").is(":checked")) {//Check Box Function
            var sound = $('.sound' + clip)[0];
            console.log(sound);
            console.log($('.sound' + clip));
            sound.currentTime = 0; //resets audio position to the start of the clip
            sound.play(); //play the sound
        }
    },
```

this is the javascript that actually runs the code offline it plays the code but when we put it up online it only plays in the console log. we are looking for help getting the sound to play

heres a link to live version so you can see that the sound doesnt work
- http://e-lemon-ators.com/

thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The server sends .mp3 and .ogg files, but with `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` header.

You need to tell the server to set proper content-type headers, for example add these rules to your `.htaccess`:

```
# MP3 audio
AddType audio/mpeg3 .mp3
AddType audio/mp3 .mp3
AddType audio/x-mpeg3 .mp3

# Ogg Vorbis audio
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/ogg .oga
```

Comment: i have added them to the .htaccess but nothing changed

Comment: @hereskellie yeah, still getting `Content-Type:text/html;` in the headers. Maybe your server doesn't allow to use `AddHeader` in .htaccess? Try contacting the your admin or support.